# Java Script hide white Flash when loading Iframe

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

Currently experiencing the annoying 'white flash' issue in IE v9-11 when dynamically generating iFrames with javascript. Essentially, I'm trying to hide the iframe until it is loaded by setting the style to display:none and then setting it to display:null once the iframe has loaded using onload. Doing so -should- show the iframe. It appears the styling is not being removed, but the function is executing. Any thoughts on how to display the iframe after it loads are appreciated.

Jsfiddle can be found here to see it live: http://jsfiddle.net/2zndpm8r/

```
var ifrm=document.createElement('IFRAME'); 
    ifrm.setAttribute('id','ifrm_ad'); 
    ifrm.setAttribute('height','90'); 
    ifrm.setAttribute('width','728'); 
    ifrm.setAttribute('frameborder','0'); 
    ifrm.setAttribute('scrolling','no'); 
    ifrm.setAttribute('marginwidth','0'); 
    ifrm.setAttribute('marginheight','0'); 
    ifrm.setAttribute('vspace','0'); 
    ifrm.setAttribute('hspace','0'); 
    ifrm.setAttribute('src','//placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&txt=728%C3%9790&w=728&h=90') 
    ifrm.style.display='none';
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    document.getElementById('ifrm_ad').onload = function(){document.getElementById('ifrm_ad').style.display= null; console.log('show iframe');};
```

Comment: so the iframe isn't being shown?

Comment: In IE, no, the Iframe is not being loaded. The code works fine in FF and Chrome :/

Comment: `It appears the styling is not being removed` ... `the Iframe is not being loaded` - two different things - which is it?

Comment: Sorry, wrong wording. I'll clarify. The iframe -is- loaded, but remains hidden after: document.getElementById('ifrm_ad').onload = function(){document.getElementById('ifrm_ad').style.display= null; console.log('show iframe');};

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion

```
var ifrm=document.createElement('IFRAME'); 
    // ...
    // snip - removed for brevity
    // ...
    ifrm.setAttribute('src','//placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&txt=728%C3%9790&w=728&h=90') 
    ifrm.style.display='none';
    ifrm.onload = function(){
        ifrm.style.display= ''; // don't use null, use empty string
        console.log('show iframe');
    };
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
```

setup the onload before adding the ifrm to the DOM
also, you can use `ifrm` here instead of the unwieldy `getElementById`